# Vowel-less CRYPTC CRSSWRD

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

For this cryptic crossword, there is a separate grid for the **consonants** of each word, and another for the **vowels**. The grids are identical.

The yellow cells will spell out the *final message* from this puzzle.

For a solution to be accepted the following are required:

- The final message
- A completes grid
- (Brief) Explanations for all the clues

## Solve the crosswords and find the message!

---

[image: Crosswords]

> **ACROSS:**
>
> 1: Scrambled senora gives explanation (6)
>   3: Money and dice all over the place occur at the same time (8)
>   5: Muddled auditor with heart of one time span (8)
>   7: Bizarre rite with backward emos is tedious (8)
>   8: America within confused rebel is not single use (8)
>   10: German betrothed shows resistance (8)
>   12: Created dutch cheese backwards (4)
>   13: Headless mouse within this rearranged home care (8)
>   14: Pb within strange dune gives petrol type (8)
>   16: Historical storage utilise surrounded by mother (6)
>   17: Very famous magnifico nicely hides (6)
>   19: Heard that vegetable had a puncture (4)
>   21: Recover a blurry, trier at end of the day (8)
>   22: Row of people strangely lupine (6)
>   23: Messily re-coated paint (8)
>   24: Fruit of grandmother surrounded by sheep noise (6)
>   25: Create a confused teenager (8)
>
> **DOWN**:
>
> 1: Hold on to disrupted retina (6)
>   2: See advert (6)
>   3: Greenhouse gas in the middle leads to entertainer (8)
>   4: Animal reverses tall grass (4)
>   5: Expected loss leads to fight (4)
>   6: Informed, I oft dine unsettled (8)
>   9: Endless suite and furniture are fitting (8)
>   10: Change beginning every day, in time (4)
>   11: Element of unsteady uremic (6)
>   12: Confused MIA wire is friendly (8)
>   13: Start in my opinion, he reversed with a bottomless alcoholic drink and committed murder (8)
>   15: A top dive messed up as not blood related (8)
>   16: Emus everywhere hide source of inspiration (4)
>   18: Footless civic with backward nail is a non-combatant (8)
>   20: Martial art is a taker, strange (6)
>   21: Term in each hidden stoat (6)

---

P.s. feedback on the cryptic clues would be much appreciated as haven't made any in a while, thanks! :)

Comment: I thought the clues will be vowel-less

Comment: @athin that would be very difficult :P

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone will try to do that :p

Comment: Feedback on the clues: you've got a *lot* of anagrams in there; I count $50\%$ of the clues as using or being an anagram. I think published crosswords aim for a more balanced distribution of clue types.  Your surface readings are weak generally: a lot of the clues just don't make sense if you read them as a whole (e.g 21d: what are terms that can be put in hidden stoat?).  However: the clues are very clear, all of the clueing indicators are correctly used and I'd definitely like to see more from you :)

Comment: @postmortes thanks!!! That’s very useful :) Yh I definitely did catch myself using anagrams way too much here lol, and should have focused more on surface reading, but my focus was to make them acceptable so that’s a start :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hidden message is

> keep safe

Grid:

> [image: img]
>
> Without the numbers:
>
>    [image: grid]

1: Scrambled senora gives explanation (6)

> reason  ('senora' anagrammed)

3: Money and dice all over the place occur at the same time (8)

> coincide ('coin' + 'dice' anagrammed)

5: Muddled auditor with heart of one time span (8)

> duration ('auditor' anagrammed + '(o)n(e)')

7: Bizarre rite with backward emos is tedious (8)

> tiresome ('rite' anagrammed + 'emos' reversed)

8: America within confused rebel is not single use (8)

> reusable ('usa' inside 'rebel' anagrammed)

10: German betrothed shows resistance (8)

> defiance  ('de' + 'fiance')

12: Created dutch cheese backwards (4)

> made ('edam' reversed)

13: Headless mouse within this rearranged home care (8)

> housesit ('(h)ouse' inside 'this' anagrammed)

14: Pb within strange dune gives petrol type (8)

> unleaded ('lead' inside 'dune' anagrammed)

16: Historical storage utilise surrounded by mother (6)

> museum ('use' inside 'mum')

17: Very famous magnifico nicely hides (6)

> iconic (hidden inside 'magnifico nicely')

19: Heard that vegetable had a puncture (4)

> leak ('leek' homonym)

21: Recover a blurry, tired end of the day (8)

> retrieve ('trier' anagrammed + 'eve')

22: Row of people strangely lupine (6)

> lineup ('lupine' anagrammed)

23: Messily re-coated paint (4)

> decorate ('recoated' anagrammed)

24: Fruit of grandmother surrounded by sheep noise (6)

> banana ('nan' inside 'baa')

25: Create a confused teenager (8)

> generate ('teenager' anagrammed)

1: Hold on to disrupted retina (6)

> retain ('retina' anagrammed)

2: See advert (6)

> notice (double meaning)

3: Greenhouse gas in the middle leads to entertainer (8)

> comedian   ('CO' + 'median')

4: Animal reverses tall grass (4)

> deer ('reed' reversed)

5: Expected loss leads to fight (4)

> duel ('due' + L)

6: Informed, I oft dine unsettled (8)

> notified ('i oft dined' anagrammed)

9: Endless suite and furniture are fitting (8)

> suitable (('suit(e)' + '(t)able')

10: Change beginning every day, in time (4)

> edit  (start of words 'every day in time')

11: Element of unsteady uremic (6)

> cerium ('uremic' anagrammed)

12: Confused MIA wire is friendly (8)

> amicable ('mia' anagrammed + 'cable')

13: Start in my opinion, he reversed with a bottomless alcoholic drink and committed murder (8)

> homicide (start of 'in my opinion he' reversed + 'cide(r)')

15: A top dive messed up as not blood related (8)

> adoptive ('a top dive' anagrammed)

16: Emus everywhere hide source of inspiration (4)

> muse (hidden in 'emus everywhere')

18: Footless civic with backward nail is a non-combatant (8)

> civilian ('civi(c)' + 'nail' reversed)

20: Martial art is a taker, strange (6)

> karate ('a taker' anagrammed)

21: Term in each hidden stoat (6)

> ermine (hidden in 'term in each')

Comment: Got to be honest, it feels a bit unfair to use this as a save-my-seat placeholder while others might be working on a full detailed solution. For a cryptic crossword I think puzzlers on this site would generally like to see an almost-completed crossword grid at the very least before posting a partial...

Comment: @Stiv as it stands, if anyone posts a solution now I’m accepting that answer. I purposefully phrased the equation as ‘solve the crosswords AND find the message’ because I want to see both. If you have a solution please do post!

Comment: @Stiv after all, you can get this from solving 6 clues

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Sorry about that. I did the work but wanted to clean it up. But you are both right.

Comment: Clarified what I’m looking for in a solution as well (@Stiv)

Comment: 16 down not quite correct (hide), not sure what I was thinking with retrieve, ive edited the clue so it works lol

Comment: A much more worthy answer now, well done for persevering Lanny :) Pretty sure the significance of the final message is purely a message of encouragement in these tricky times...

Comment: @stiv cheers, mate.

Comment: @LannyStrack as you’ve solved this all but seem to be struggling a lil to make the grid look clean do you want me to just upload an image of my files in grid? After all I have one sitting in excel :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - That's OK. I will do it. I am still working on it. Thanks.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - The way the grid looks now is about as good as I am going to get it, I think. If, in your judgment, including your solution grid as well would be helpful, feel free to do that. Cheers.

Comment: @LannyStrack I’ll add mine as well, because I have one without the numbers in the way which I think is the issue, congrats on solving!!